How to print pdf in C#
I need to print an existing PDF where the printer selection window is displayed to the user in C#, without a paid library. And print immediately afterwards.
I have this snippet of code, using PdfiumViewer, but it doesn't work, because it doesn't find the DLL:
public static void PrintPDF(string path)
{
try
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    printDialog.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();

    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        printerSettings.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        printerSettings.Copies = (short)1;

        PageSettings pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings);
        pageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(path))
        {
            using (PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
            {
                printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
                printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
                printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Throw new Exception(ex.Message)
}
}

I tried with PdfDocument, PrintDocument but none of them worked.

Could you add the error message?

This question is similar to: Print Pdf in C#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm using PdfiumPrinter in a NET6 WPF-Project
EDIT working example:
First add package PdfiumPrinter to your project
//PDF-File to print:
string printFile = "c:\\temp\\test.pdf";

//Printername as listed in Windows
string printerName ="Lexmark FirstFloor";
var printer = new PdfPrinter(printerName);
    
//If nessesary set some options:
//    printer.Settings.Duplex=System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Vertical;
//     printer.PageSettings.PaperSource = paper;
//     printer.Settings.PrintRange = printRange;
//     printer.Settings.FromPage = printPageFrom;
//     printer.Settings.ToPage = printPageTo;
    
// For Windows PrinterQueue
string documentName = "My windows printQueue name";
    
    
printer.Print(fileName: printFile, 
              copies: 1,
              documentName: documentName);


Can you give me the complete code?

Ok I colud not simulate it in older .NET Frameworks but i am sharing a code and refrences that works.
.NET FrameWork 6.0.
You need following libraries and make sure copy local is true, so that Dlls are copied to local debug/release folders.
Required Libraries:

Nuget Library: PdfiumPrinter
Nuget Library: PdfiumPrinter.Native

After making sure that you have above libraries use following code:
 public static void PrintPDF(string path)
 {
 try
 {
     PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
     printDialog.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();

     if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
         printerSettings.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
         printerSettings.Copies = (short)1;

         PageSettings pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings);
         pageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

         using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(path))
         {
             using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
             {
                 printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
                 printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
                 printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
                 printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>{Console.WriteLine("Printing page...");};
                 printDocument.Print();
             }
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while printing the PDF: {ex.Message}");
 }

}
